# Keep a header view when using a navigation controller

Tags: ios, user-interface, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I have a label I placed at the top of the screen as a header. I want to keep that viewable and still present when I add a navigation controller by embedding it.

I am mostly using the storyboard to help me create the UI.

This is what the app looks like without a navigation controller:

[image: App screenshot with orange header]

However, if I add a navigation controller I get the following:

[image: App screenshot where nav bar has replaced orange header]

Certainly I would like to maintain a navigation controller so that I won't have to incorporate my own buttons which control navigation. As I understand it, at this time the Marketplace logo is hidden behind the nav controller.

Comment: If you insert your logo after the view controller is embedded in the navigation controller you can pin it to the bottom of the nav controller. You could just move it down from where it is but maybe delete and reinsert would be quicker.

Comment: Explain how you're placing the "header" view.

Comment: I just put a label at the top using the storyboard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use two methods here :

1) Keep using your label, and hide the navigation bar , your app will still have navigation, just the top navigation bar will be hidden.
For this, use this code:

```
 viewDidLoad() 
{
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
}
```

2) The second method is a alternate to what you want, but its good if you Need text At top only. In this we will not use label, instead we'll set title of the navigation bar itself.

```
viewDidLoad() 
{
self.navigationItem.title = "MarketPlace"
}
```

Maybe there are more methods, but these two i've used.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `navigationItem.titleView = yourView`

Comment: Could you explain how to set that up? I assume navigationitem will have to be "initialized" somehow as it looks to be an object.

Comment: navigationItem is part of your UINavigationController that should already be initialised. So in the view that has a navcontroller just type in  navigationItem.titleView = yourView (just add your label)

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C it would be something like this:

```
navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
```